Open the link outside of Telegram's browser
I'm creating a mini-application inside Telegram that includes a feature to navigate to a website.
Is there a way to ensure that, when a user opens a link in Telegram, it opens in their default browser (e.g., Chrome, Safari) instead of Telegram's in-app browser?
In other words, how can I programmatically make sure that users are redirected to their external browser, rather than Telegram's built-in one?
Unfortunately, some functions on the website don't work properly when opened in Telegram's internal browser.
window.Telegram.WebApp.openLink(import.meta.env.VITE_OSMICARDS_ANKETA);

